# Gracefully handle expired HttpSession in Spring WebFlow

Tags: spring-webflow

(From [SpringSource forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?108833-Handling-expired-session-gracefully).)

When the `HttpSession` has expired and the user re-submits a page in the flow, he/she is sent back to the beginning of the flow. All I want to add to this behavior is a message explaining why it occurred. "You were inactive, so you have been restarted..."

What's the easiest/best-practice way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The default behavior, in [FlowHandlerAdapter.defaultHandleException()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/mvc/servlet/FlowHandlerAdapter.html#defaultHandleException%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.webflow.core.FlowException,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29), "attempts to start a new execution of the ended or expired flow".

It looks like a WebFlow way to handle this would be to provide a `FlowHandler` with a [handleException()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/mvc/servlet/FlowHandler.html#handleException%28org.springframework.webflow.core.FlowException,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method that checks for an `instanceof NoSuchFlowExecutionException`, then do something like construct a redirect URL or place something on Session scope that can later be removed once utilized.

Due to the way WebFlow uses redirects, I don't think any other scopes would allow such a flag or message to be used later when the new flow's view renders.

However, simply detecting a new Session in an `Interceptor` or even a `Filter` would seem to be just as effective. Which is what I ended up doing in my previous investigation of this, as documented in the referenced forum thread. I was just hoping for something prettier.

Also, by the time the new flow begins, a new Session ID has already been created, so there's no way to initially detect this condition from within the flow.xml.

Sample filter logic:

```java
if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
    log.info("Expired Session ID: " + request.getRequestedSessionId());
    response.sendRedirect("sessionExpired");
}
else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Sample Interceptor:

```java
public class SessionExpiredInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
            response.sendRedirect("sessionExpired");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
FlowController has a default handlerAdapter. To customize session exceptions you are required to write your own custom handler adapter and register it with the flow controller bean as below:

```
<bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
.
.<property name="flowHandlerAdapter" ref="customFlowHandlerAdapter"/>

.
</bean>

<bean id="customFlowHandlerAdapter" class="gov.mo.courts.pbw.adapters.CustomFlowHandlerAdapter"
     p:flowExecutor-ref="flowExecutor"/>
```

Step 2:
CustomFlowHandlerAdapter
In this class override defaultHandleException method. this is the method that webflow invokes in case of exceptions and re-initializes session. please note, new session has already been created till this point. Only the exception type will tell you at this point that the previous session timed out.

```
public class PbwFlowHandlerAdapter extends FlowHandlerAdapter{
protected void defaultHandleException(String flowId, FlowException e,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        if(e instanceof NoSuchFlowExecutionException){
            if(e.getCause() instanceof NoSuchConversationException){
                //"use newly created session object within request object to save your   customized message."
            }
        }
        super.defaultHandleException(flowId, e, request, response);
    }
```

The first view page of your app should be able to show this message.

```
<%
                        if (session.getAttribute(YOUR_CUSTOM_MSG_KEY) != null) {
                    %>
                    <p class="errormessage">
                    <%=session.getAttribute(YOUR_CUSTOM_MSG_KEY)%>
                    </p>
                    <%
                    //once the message has been shown, remove it from the session
                    //as a new session has already been started at this time
                        session.removeAttribute(YOUR_CUSTOM_MSG_KEY);
                            }
                    %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Jira request I had opened](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1598), WebFlow developer says,

> [Custom FlowHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-config-flow-handlers) is the extension point for an expired session. You
>   can redirect to the flow and append a query param, something like
>   restarted=true, and then in the flow declare an `<input
>   name="restarted" type="boolean" value="flashScope.restarted" />`.

I haven't been able to confirm, but wanted to share the information.