# How to handle session expired in spring web flow?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm writing a web application with Spring boot, Spring web flow and thymeleaf. When the user session expires the csrf token in the registration form expires.
How can I handle the session expiration showing a template file in Spring web flow?

Comment: Not the same question, but might have something relevant/helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9909774/796761

Answer (score 0):

Session should be handled by Spring Security. You can redirect the current user to another page by adding configuration like this:

```
http.sessionManagement()
.expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html")
.invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html");
```

In Thymeleaf, you can use `session` variable and add `th:if` attribute to check if session exist or something similar:

```
${session.isEmpty()}
```

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22120387/2230060